# Web API Conditional Serialization of properties using attributes

Tags: asp.net-web-api

How to include/exclude properties from a WEB API response based on a user's role using attributes? For example:

```
public class Employee 
{ 
    public string FullName { get; set;}

    [DataMember(Role="SystemAdmin")] // included only for SystemAdmins
    public string SSN { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use conditional serialization depending on what serializer(s) you are using in web api.

If you are just returning JSON from Web API its simple - I use only the JSON serializer and this solution works for me.  By default Web API uses JSON.Net for JSON serialization.  You can add a ShouldSerialize method that returns a bool.  In the should serialize you can test if the user IsInRole

```
public class Employee
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Manager { get; set; }

   public bool ShouldSerializeManager()
   {
    // don't serialize the Manager property for anyone other than Bob..
    return (Name == "Bob");
   }
```

}

More [details](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm)

The [JsonIgnore] attribute is all or nothing when using the JSON.Net Web API serialization.

Other serializers require different approaches...

The XmlSerializer also supports this but you have to enable it

```
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

The datacontract serializer is the default.

If using this you would have to add logic into the properties and omit them if null.. This can be a problem if you use the class elsewhere.  The [IgnoreDataMember] attribute is all or nothing.

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
  private string firstName;
  [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
  public string FirstName
  {
    get
    {
        //Put here any condition for serializing
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstName) ? null : firstName;
    }
    set
    {
        firstName = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was aware of the ShouldSerialize[PropertyName] approach of JSON.Net, however I was wanting to use attributes instead to avoid having to rename ShouldSerialize methods when property names change. The ShouldSerialize approach is prone to misspelling and neglect, therefore, if not careful, properties could get serialized that should be excluded from responses. I am going to upvote the answer but it wasn't the answer I was hoping for